# How to call Android Api from NativeScript (LAC, CID, MCC, MNC)

Tags: nativescript

I have following piece of code created in Android Studio:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

        final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephony.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {


            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            final GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony.getCellLocation();
            if (location != null) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"LAC: " + location.getLac() + " CID: " + location.getCid(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

If NativeScript have 100% access do Android API how reach same result in .ts NativeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer the docs on [Java to JS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) to understand how the native api calls are marshalled into JS / TS.

You will be able to get the current activity from application module with `application.android.foregroundActivity`. So the code below should return instance of telephony manager.

```
const telephony = application.android.foregroundActivity.getSystemService(android.content.Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)
```

Use [nativescript-permissions](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-permissions) plugin to acquire permissions or to know whether your app already has the required permissions on device.

There is also [nativescript-toast](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-toast) plugin that implements cross platform toast messages.

Comment: and use tns-platform-declarations (and reference the correct version.
see: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/tns-platform-declarations) to have the correct IntelliSense on objects like "Context" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Manoj for useful help.
So steps that needed to be taken are:

1. Install:
   `npm install tns-platform-declarations --save-dev`
2. Add two lines into references.d.ts, in my case it was in file `ProjectName\references.d.ts`

   `/// <reference path="node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />`

   `/// <reference path="node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />`
3. Install nativescript-permissions plugin: `tns plugin add nativescript-permissions`
4. Install nativescript-toast plugin `$ tns plugin add nativescript-toast`
5. Import libraries on the begining of file

   `var application = require("application");`

   `const permissions = require( "nativescript-permissions" );`

   `import * as Toast from 'nativescript-toast';`
6. And write code to get LAC, CID, MCC, MNC

```
buttonGetInfoTap(args) { 
    const telephonyService = application.android.foregroundActivity.getSystemService(android.content.Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, "I need these permissions because I'm cool")
    .then( () => {
      if (telephonyService.getPhoneType() == android.telephony.TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
        let location = <android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation>telephonyService.getCellLocation();
        if (location != null) {
            console.log("LAC: " + location.getLac() + " CID: " + location.getCid())
            Toast.makeText("LAC: " + location.getLac() + " CID: " + location.getCid(), "long").show();
            const networkOperator = telephonyService.getNetworkOperator();
            const MCC =networkOperator.substring(0,3)
            const MNC =networkOperator.substring(3)
            Toast.makeText("MCC:"+MCC+"MNC:"+MNC, "long").show();
        }
      }
    })
    .catch( () => {
      Toast.makeText("No permission", "long").show();
    });
}
```